# Group by field by a string format

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have a field that contains versions, the values are a bit different and are never full so I have values like 5.0.1.1255, 4.2.2, 4.2.x, 4.0, 4.x. I'm not sure if what I want is very possible but I want to get a count for each dot version so I'd like to know how many 5.0, 4.2, 4.0 but the versions will be dynamic so some day there will be a 5.1, 5.2 etc.

So for example, manually getting I can do:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ticket_meta m WHERE m.product_version LIKE "4.1%") as ext_4_1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM ticket_meta m WHERE m.product_version LIKE "4.2%") as ext_4_2
```

but of course I'm going to have to constantly update that query. Is there a way to make this much more automated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Up to version 9.9, this script should work:

```
SELECT LEFT(product_version, 3) Version, COUNT(*) as Quantity
FROM ticket_meta
WHERE product_version
GROUP BY LEFT(product_version, 3)
```

This is for T-SQL but I guess it should work or at least be very similar for MySQL.

If you really need those values as columns and not rows, you should probably use a pivot table.

PS: I bet those are Ext JS versions. ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is easy in MySQL.  Just use `substring_index()`:

```
select substring_index(version, '.', 2) as MajorMinor, count(*)
from tickeet_meta
group by MajorMinor;
```

This produces the results on separate rows, not in separate columns.  To get the results in separate columns would require doing a dynamic pivot.